# Product and list view page table

Tags: magento-1.9

In Magento 9.2, i have different price in view and list page. So, what are the tables used for price in catalog page and product view page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

value column in catalog_product_entity_decimal for the Product Page and price column for the catalog_product_index_price for catalog page